# Flask request with post call not getting data

Tags: python, apache, flask, mod-wsgi

I have mod_wsgi configured with apache and forwarding the post request other application server for heave processing my flask app.py:

```
@app.route('/api/users/login.json', methods=['POST'])
@require_appkey
def user_login():
    """ user login only for testing """
    db = mongo.db
    #import ipdb
    #ipdb.set_trace()
    #app.logger.debug('A value for debugging')
    #print "getting here new"
    test = request.values
    test1 = request.stream.read()
    test2= request.data
    test3 = request.json
    test4 = request.form 
    #print "username: ", test
    #print "test1: ", test1, test2, test3, test4
    if (test or test1 or test2 or test3 or test4):
        result = {"status": True, "msg": "login post call", "data": [test, test1, test2, test3, test4]}
    else:
        result = {"status": False, "msg": "login post call", "data": None}
    format_result = {"result": result}
    json_results = json.dumps(format_result, default=json_util.default)
    return json_results, 200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
```

flask.wsgi:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/share/python_flask_api/')
from app import app as application
```

I not getting any data in post when the call is coming though the mod_wsgi but when I change mod_wsgi with my local flask development server I'm getting post data, I want to why the post data is not coming from mod_wsgi config. Please provide any direction to debug.

Comment: How have you got mod_wsgi configured, embedded or daemon mode? Use something like http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/DebuggingTechniques#Displaying_Request_Environment to determine what the WSGI environ contains that is received for the request. Ensure the request has a CONTENT_LENGTH and wasn't using chunked transfer encoding.

Comment: @SnehalParmar you should probably share how

Comment: @SnehalParmar I am getting same issue, can you please share how you resolved this issue?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I didn't remember the solution but I just changed some config in mod_wsgi server settings.